# Python отключение логов в http.server

Tags: python, http

При запуске сервера через http.server при каждом обращении к серверу пишется ip-адрес и время запроса. Можно ли отключить отображение этих логов в консоли?

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class http_requests(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/image.png':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'image/png')
            self.end_headers()
            with open('image.png', 'rb') as file:
                self.wfile.write(file.read())
            file.close()

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 443), http_requests)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Покажите как его запускаете

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `log_message(format, ...)`
> Logs an arbitrary message to `sys.stderr`. This is typically overridden to create custom error logging mechanisms. The format argument is a standard `printf`-style format string, where the additional arguments to `log_message()` are applied as inputs to the formatting. The client ip address and current date and time are prefixed to every message logged.

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.log_message)

Переопредели этот метод (или соседний чуть выше) в обработчике если запускаешь программно.

Если запускаешь как модуль, то можно просто заглушить вывод в `/dev/null`.

Comment: Получилось отключить после правки исходников библиотеки. Закомментировал строки с выводом и добавил pass.

Comment: @MrPikokon зачем библиотеку ломаете, рядом с do_GET в своей программе опишите метод

Comment: Можно код, не понимаю, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

добавь у себя в хандлер перед всеми do_***(GET,POST)
`def log_message(*args):`
`pass`